# how to use gigya .net sdk functions in my asp.net program for login and registration via social networking and regular way

Tags: c#

in HTML page i use JavaScript api of gigya for loginUI for see user the social networking sites options  for login but how to use this in my code behind using .NET SDK methods

Comment: Your question is too vague and doesn't provide specific enough information about your intended server-side use-case.  What, exactly, are you attempting to accomplish from the .NET implementation? Login? Passing the session from the client-side?  Please provide specific details about what you are hoping to accomplish

Comment: i am trying to read data which is gigya login page javascript api sends to gigya cloud database into my page load of  my website aspx.cs